# Exception when adding range index to Azure DocumentDB collection

Tags: c#, azure-cosmosdb

I'm trying to add a range index to a specific property in an Azure DocumentDB collection as described in [this](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/articles/documentdb-indexing-policies/) article. When my code to create the collection is executed I get the following error:

> The special mandatory indexing path \\"\/\\" is not provided in any
>   of the path type sets. Please provide this path in one of the sets.

The code I'm using to create the collection is:

```
var collection = new DocumentCollection { id = "myCollectionID" };

collection.IndexingPolicy.IncludedPaths.Add(new IndexingPath
{
    IndexType = IndexType.Range,
    Path = "/\"TimeStamp\"/\"Epoch\"/?",
    NumericPrecision = 7
});

this._client.CreateDocumentCollectionAsync(database.SelfLink, collection);
```

The code works if I set the path of the index to simply "/", but I'd prefer to be able to create the index on specific properties. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have to include "/" as an additional IncludedPath like:

```
var collection = new DocumentCollection { id = "myCollectionID" };

collection.IndexingPolicy.IncludedPaths.Add(new IndexingPath
{
    IndexType = IndexType.Range,
    Path = "/\"TimeStamp\"/\"Epoch\"/?",
    NumericPrecision = 7
});

collection.IndexingPolicy.IncludedPaths.Add(new IndexingPath
{
    IndexType = IndexType.Hash,
    Path = "/"
});

this._client.CreateDocumentCollectionAsync(database.SelfLink, collection);
```

Alternatively, if you want to exclude every other path completely from indexing, you can do the following:

```
var collection = new DocumentCollection { id = "myCollectionID" };

collection.IndexingPolicy.IncludedPaths.Add(new IndexingPath
{
    IndexType = IndexType.Range,
    Path = "/\"TimeStamp\"/\"Epoch\"/?",
    NumericPrecision = 7
});

collection.IndexingPolicy.ExcludedPaths.Add("/");

this._client.CreateDocumentCollectionAsync(database.SelfLink, collection);
```

DocumentDB always requires you to either include or exclude "/", so that the indexing scheme is unambiguous. Hope this helps.

Comment: Has this changed in recent releases? I was unable to use IndexingPath or IndexType due to them being listed as "internal". I was able to do this using the IncludePath class.

Comment: Yes, the syntax of this has changed recently.